# Is Soul Calibur V's online play cross-platform?

Tags: soul-calibur-5

If I get the Xbox 360 version and my friend gets the PS3 version, can we play vs each other online?

Comment: Hah, that would be really cool, but I don't think Any games do that!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. The multiplayer is run on the PSN (SEN?) and XBL networks seperately. You can not compete with players on the rival console.

Comment: Ah, that's a shame, but more or less what I expected.

Comment: Going to give it a bit more time before accepting in case anyone had any insights otherwise, but I'm not expecting it.